# Warning message : Specifying types in document index requests is deprecated

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I implement `ElasticSearchConsumer class` program which is supposed to return the Id document. The running program desplay a warning message and return just `twitter` :

```
déc. 23, 2020 9:41:10 AM org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient logResponse
WARNING: request [POST https://kafka-course-6054260476.us-east-1.bonsaisearch.net:443/twitter/tweets?timeout=1m] returned 1 warnings: [299 Elasticsearch-7.2.0-508c38a "[types removal] Specifying types in document index requests is deprecated, use the typeless endpoints instead (/{index}/_doc/{id}, /{index}/_doc, or /{index}/_create/{id})."]
[main] INFO com.gihub.simplesteph.kafka.tutorial3.ElasticSearchConsumer - twitter

Process finished with exit code 0
```

This is the code :

```
package com.gihub.simplesteph.kafka.tutorial3;

import org.apache.http.HttpHost;
import org.apache.http.auth.AuthScope;
import org.apache.http.auth.UsernamePasswordCredentials;
import org.apache.http.client.CredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.BasicCredentialsProvider;
import org.apache.http.impl.nio.client.HttpAsyncClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexRequest;
import org.elasticsearch.action.index.IndexResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClient;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestClientBuilder;
import org.elasticsearch.client.RestHighLevelClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.xcontent.XContentType;
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import java.io.IOException;

public class ElasticSearchConsumer {

    public  static RestHighLevelClient createClient(){

        // replace with your own credentials
        String hostname = "kafka-course-6054260476.us-east-1.bonsaisearch.net";
        String username = "48h3frssnm";
        String password = "8iliybmly0";

        //don't do if you run a local ES
        final CredentialsProvider credentialsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();
        credentialsProvider.setCredentials(AuthScope.ANY, new UsernamePasswordCredentials(username, password));

        RestClientBuilder builder = RestClient.builder(
                new HttpHost(hostname, 443, "https"))
                .setHttpClientConfigCallback(new RestClientBuilder.HttpClientConfigCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public HttpAsyncClientBuilder customizeHttpClient(HttpAsyncClientBuilder httpAsyncClientBuilder) {
                        return httpAsyncClientBuilder.setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credentialsProvider);
                    }
                });
        RestHighLevelClient client = new RestHighLevelClient(builder);
        return client;
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(ElasticSearchConsumer.class.getName());
        RestHighLevelClient client = createClient();

        String jsonString = "{ \"foo\": \"bar\" }";

        IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("twitter", "tweets" ).source(jsonString, XContentType.JSON);

        IndexResponse indexResponse = client.index(indexRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
        String id = indexResponse.getIndex();
        logger.info(id);

        //close the client gracefully
        client.close();

    }

}
```

This is the `pom.xml` file :

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>kafka-beginners-course</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.example</groupId>
        <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <artifactId>kafka-consumer-elasticsearch</artifactId>

    <properties>
        <maven.compiler.source>8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>8</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.elasticsearch.client/elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-high-level-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.1</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.kafka/kafka-clients -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>2.0.0</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.25</version>
            <!--            <scope>test</scope>-->
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore-nio</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.14</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.5.13</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.4.14</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>1.15</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use likewise its removed warning message.

```
IndexRequest indexRequest = new IndexRequest("twitter", "_doc",tweetId).
```

Answer (score 0):

The warning does not related to what returned, it is related to deprecated constructor for `IndexRequest()` and you can ignore it or should not pass type argument(second argument) to constructor.

you retrieved the index name by `getIndex()` method but you should retrieve the Id by `getId()` method.